# SpringBoot: @Value for Proxy-settings (System.setProperty)

Tags: java, proxy, spring-boot, truststore, system-properties

My `application.yml` configuration looks like this:

```
proxy:
  host: myProxyDNS
  port: 8080
  trustedStore:
    filename: keystore.jks
    type: JKS
    password: MY_PASSWORD_FOR_THE_KEYSTORE
```

The class how manage all the proxy stuff looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class ProxyConfigurator {

@Value("${proxy.host}")
private String proxyHost;

@Value("${proxy.port}")
private String proxyPort;

@Value("${proxy.trustedStore.filename}")
private String trustedStoreFilename;

@Value("${proxy.trustedStore.type}")
private String trustedStoreType;

@Value("${proxy.trustedStore.password}")
private String trustedStorePassword;

public void setProxy() {
  System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", proxyHost);
  System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", proxyPort);

  System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", getPathForFile(trustedStoreFilename));
  // and so on ...
}
```

In my "Main" Class which was called by `SpringApplication.run()` looks like that:

```
@Autowired
private ProxyConfigurator proxyConfigurator;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
   proxyConfigurator.setProxy();
   // Call another autowired (third-party class) to make an HTTP call
}
```

This works fine (all properties are set). BUT in my "main" class i have also some other autowired classes (third-party) which i used to make an HTTP call. The problem is now, that this third-party classes ignore all System properties that are set after their initialization.

I've found some posts on SO where the proxy settings was set by arguments (`-D`), but i think this not a solution for me.

Sure i can use a second `SpringApplication.run`: the first one sets the proxy, the second runs my app. But this feels bad.

Have anyone a good suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the third party http requirements the same as for your proxy? I dont understand your real problem. Please be more specific on the problem.

Comment: The third party componentens makes an http call. Because they don't provide an api to set the proxy the only way is to set the proxy as system property. This works well if i set the proxy in my SpringBoot Application class. But i want to use the @Value annotation so the proxy can be set in a yml file.